# What's wrong with this questions vote-to-close count?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't vote again if previous vote has expired?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2815/cant-vote-again-if-previous-vote-has-expired)

There is something odd with [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/329798/using-avahi-on-dreamplug-ubuntu-with-ipads): It's definitely off-topic and should be closed, but when I try to vote it to close, I get the message that I already did (which might be possible), but the vote count that is normally displayed in parenthesis is never displayed, but it should display at least `close (1)`.